# Elastic Search - Operator in NEST (Search Query with Operator as string)

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elastic-stack

I have a query as follows written in C# and using NEST client 6.x.

```
.Should(
    m => m.QueryString(qs => qs
   .Query(searchOptions.SearchTerm)
   .Fields(ff => ff.Fields(fields))
   .DefaultOperator(Operator.And)
   ),
```

I need to pass Operator Parameter as string but it isn't accepting string values.
Is there a way to pass the operator as a string?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse input string to `Operator` enum within this code:

```
var parsed = Enum.TryParse("or", true, out Operator parsedOperator);
```

and then use `parsedOperator` in your query descriptor like:

```
elasticClient.Search<object>(s => s
    .Query(q => q.QueryString(qs => qs.DefaultOperator(parsedOperator))));
```